# Select couple of id equals in two values

Tags: mysql

i got this two table for  example

```
+----+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |   | id | c1 | c2 | c4 |
+----+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 50 | 55 | 20 |   | 20 | 50 | 55 | 24 |
+----+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
| 12 | 15 | 10 | 70 |   | 26 | 21 | 82 | 11 |
+----+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
| 18 | 15 | 10 | 88 |   | 27 | 15 | 10 | 13 |
+----+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
```

I want to get the couple of the id's with the same `c1` and `c2` values, for the example above i have to get this output:

```
+----+----+
| id | id |
+----+----+
| 10 | 20 |
+----+----+
| 12 | 27 |
+----+----+
| 12 | 18 |
+----+----+
| 18 | 27 |
+----+----+
```

Comment: @llyes Ghomrani please check my answer. I have changed in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join the two tables like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table1 AS t2  ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
                        AND t1.id != t2.id
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
FROM table2 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2  ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
                        AND t1.id != t2.id;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/442d8/4)**:

```
| id1 | id2 |
|-----|-----|
|  10 |  20 |
|  12 |  27 |
|  18 |  27 |
|  18 |  12 |
|  12 |  18 |
```

Comment: by this you can't get the 3rd line in the result

Comment: @IlyesGhomrani There is no id=18  in the second table, or do you want to match the table with itself??

Comment: Yes. i want to match each table with itself and other table also.

Comment: can we delete the duplicate (keep just one (18-12) or (12-18))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID AS ID1 ,T2.ID AS ID2 FROM TABLE_1 T1,TABLE_2 T2
WHERE T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND
T1.C2 = T2.C2 
UNION 
SELECT ID1,ID2 FROM (
    SELECT  T1.ID AS ID1 , T2.ID 
    AS ID2 FROM TABLE_1 T1,  TABLE_1 T2
    WHERE T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND
    T1.C2 = T2.C2 AND T1.ID! = T2.ID)
WHERE (ID1,ID2) IN ((ID1,ID2),(ID2,ID1)) AND (ID2,ID1)IN ((ID1,ID2),
(ID2,ID1)) AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Result:

```
| id1 | id2 |
|-----|-----|
|  10 |  20 |
|  12 |  27 |
|  18 |  12 |
|  18 |  27 |
```

Comment: you also need to add a section for matching the second table with itself and i don't need to get the duplicated values